# NHibernate generating duplicate ID values when deployed on multiple servers

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Im using this code to generate my ID's

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
```

This has been working fine for ages, but since moving to a different server and after it successfully adds a number of records it is now throwing the following error when trying to insert a new record

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TableName'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'TableName'.
The statement has been terminated
```

This is how the new record is saved

```
using (var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
{                
    _session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Any idea what could be causing the problem or a better way that I should be doing this?

Edit: I've just found out that this code is now running on multiple servers so I think I'll have to change the Id generation method.

Comment: is there more than one process concurrently writing ?

Comment: @FelicePollano It has now been deployed to multiple load balanced servers so this is likely the problem.

Comment: @RichardD Is it needed you use the Id created in that way? Have you considered using Guid Comb?

Comment: @RichardD You have to change strategy, maybe HiLo would do in your case...

Comment: @FelicePollano Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @RichardD thanks I posted a complete reoply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a drawback that prevent use Increment generator when multiple process concurrently saves the entities. You can use an HiLo generator as a replacement.